# Why when we ask for the square of 4 on c++ doesn't give the +-2 result like the result on matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab

When we ask for the square root of `4` in C++, why doesn't it give the  `+-2` result like in MATLAB?

Comment: because there is not innate type, which can hold "+-2" value

Comment: I'm curious. How exactly are you getting `+-2` from the square root of `4` using Matlab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Starl1ght has pointed out in comments C++ only [has `shor int`, `int`, `long int`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm). This can only hold one (either positive or negative) value.

C++ is a programming language built to be efficient and as close to machine as possible for speed. It would be too much (unnecessary) trouble to create an class to hold +/- value and return this. Instead it relies on programmers knowledge of mathematics to understand this.

Matlab is a [numerical computing environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). This would justify the extra overhead in creating and handling a data type to hold +/- values.